# Comparing rows of 2D list of unequal size with try catch causes program to jump around erratically

Tags: python

I have a 2D list called Matrix. Each column can have an unequal number of rows. I need to compare the rows. If a row doesnt exist for a column then my try catch skips it and leaves the variable the row is set to as an empty string.

The problem is that the code will jump around to different exception blocks when an index doesn't exist. For example, if z is out of range then the code might jump to the exception rule immediately after y and execute z again. Sometimes this loop exits with values of K like 5 when it should never go past 3.

How can i stop the code from jumping around like this and proceed to the exception rule immediately after try. Is there a better way to compare the rows of a 2D list with different numbers of rows without erratic try catch behavior?

```
while(k < 3):
 x = ""
 y = ""
 z = ""
 k = 0
 try:
     x = Matrix[0][i]
 except IndexError:
     k = k + 1

 try:
     y = Matrix[1][i]
 except IndexError:
     k = k + 1

 try:
     z = Matrix[2][i]
 except IndexError:
     k = k + 1

 if k == 3:  #Prevents submitting x,y,z if they are all empty strings
     break
 i = i + 1
 results = compare(x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you could use the [`itertools` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) to achieve your goals:

```
>>> Matrix = [["a","b","c"],["d"], ["e", "f"]]
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> for item in zip_longest(*Matrix, fillvalue=""):
...     print(item)
...
('a', 'd', 'e')
('b', '', 'f')
('c', '', '')
```

Comment: No, because K is incremented when "i" is beyond the index of Matrix. "i" increments forever until "i" is beyond the index of Matrix[0][i], Matrix[1][i], and Matrix[2][i]. That would cause 3 exceptions consecutively making k = 3 and ending the loop. Of course thats not what happens. My program jumps to the exception block that's above the try its currently in rather than below.

Comment: I see. Then `while True:` would also work because of the `break`. But you'd better use Python's built-in capabilities for zipping iterators of unequal length. I've reduced my answer to only that suggestion.

Comment: I doubt your program jumps to the wrong `except` block, especially since we have no way of reproducing your problem.